# Bash command with multiple input files

Tags: bash, sorting, stdin

In bash, is there a way to do some kind of loop to pass multiple inputs to a command, *i.e.* to shorten something like

```
cmd < 1.txt < 2.txt < ... < 100.txt
```

My exact use-case is that I have a bunch of sorted gzipped files that I want to merge together into another gzipped file:

```
sort --merge <(zcat 1.txt.gz) <(zcat 2.txt.gz) ... <(zcat 100.txt.gz) | gzip > out.txt.gz
```

I want to avoid unziping them separately if possible.

Edit:
I should note that the files are huge, and that's why I want to take advantage of the `--merge` option, and not just concatenate them and resort the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
zcat *.txt.gz | sort -m | gzip > out.txt.gz
```

But as you pointed out, that's plain wrong. You're right, for `sort -m` to make sense you need multiple files.

Try this instead:

```
x=; for i in *.txt.gz; do x="$x <(zcat $i)"; done
eval "sort -m $x" | gzip > out.txt.gz
```

Comment: I think you'll need `-c` on the `gzip`

Comment: Maybe in older versions. Runs fine for me on old-ish Mac.

Comment: But then all the files will be concatenated *before* the "merge sort", hence not using the fact that the individual files were already sorted, and it will be slower then the version in my question (if you ignore the time to type the command :P). Also I think the -m option doesn't make sense in your command.

Comment: +1 A rare legitimate use of `eval`. Re: `-c`, it's not needed when it compresses from standard input.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. I hate `eval`. It's good to be backed up that it was justified.